# Photo app in Yosemite

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I just had Yosemite loaded onto my laptop and there is no Photo app (nor iPhoto). I do have ImageCapture, but I would like to work with my albums in either Photo or iPhoto. Can't find it at the AppStore to download... How can I get one of them? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Yosemite? Photos came along with [I think] 10.10.3, so if you're below that, I'd suggest the [combo updater to 10.10.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832) & it should be installed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep posted for updates!**

Make sure you check for updates to your system. Also, upgrade your system to El Capitan to get a better experience and new features.